# Let $p_n\ $ be the $n-$th prime. Is there a decreasing positive real sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\sum a_n$ diverges, but $\sum a_{p_n}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

> Let the $\ n-$th prime be denoted by $\ p_n.\ $ Is there a (not
> necessarily strictly) decreasing sequence of positive real numbers $\
> (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ such that $\ \sum a_n\ $ diverges, but $\
> \sum a_{p_n}\ $ converges?

Remarks/thoughts:

- $\ a_n = \frac{1}{n}\ $ fails because $\ \sum\frac{1}{n}\ $ diverges but so does $\ \sum \frac{1}{p_n}.$
- If $\ \sum a_n\ $ diverges and $\ k\in\mathbb{N}\ $ then any subseries of the form $\ \sum a_{kn}\ $ also diverges. To see this, consider the contrapositive of this statement. However, there is no $\ k\ $ to compare to prime numbers because the $\ n-$th prime is approximately $\ n\ln(n) \gg n\ $ for large $\ n.$
- Maybe there are arguments you can make based on the asymptotic behaviour of the primes - but I am not very good at these, so would be interested to see some.
- Or maybe there are other, easier methods, which again I don't see.

Comment: How about $a_n =\frac{1}{n\log n}$?

Comment: @Gary why does $\ \frac{1}{p_n\log(p_n)}\ $ converge?

Comment: Since $$
\frac{1}{{p_n \log p_n }} \sim \frac{1}{{n\log n\log (n\log n)}} \sim \frac{1}{{n\log ^2 n}}.
$$ Now use the integral or the Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: I thought that sums like $\ \sum\frac{1}{n\log^2(n)}\ $ diverge, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Yes you are, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Examples

Comment: I said "Now use *the integral* or the Cauchy condensation test.".

Comment: lol I missed that part of your comment, oops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Gary in the comments,

$\ a_n = \frac{1}{n\log n}\ $ is an example of such a function.

$\ \sum\frac{1}{n\log n}\ $ diverges by, for example, the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

$$ a_{p_n}=\frac{1}{p_n \log p_n} \sim \frac{1}{n\log n \log(n\log n)}\sim \frac{1}{n \log^2n}. $$

Since $\ \sum\frac{1}{n \log^2n}\ $ converges by the integral test or Cauchy's condensation test, it follows from the [Limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) that $\ \sum \frac{1}{a_{p_n}}\ $ converges also.

Comment: Also there is an elementary proof (not using the PNT): from $\pi(2k)-\pi(k) \le \frac1{\log k} \log {2k\choose k} \le \frac1{\log k} A k$ we get that $\pi(k) \log \pi(k)\le B k$, taking $k=p_n$ we have the convergence of $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac1{p_n \log(p_n)}$